# build.gradle: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore

Tags: android, flutter, deprecated, android-studio-3.6

I am new to flutter development.

When I opened my android project in android studio then I got this warning and unable to understand exactly what to do?

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397617/progruard-and-r8-being-deprecated-android-studio-3-6) but not clear to me.

Please tell exactly what to do? (Keep in mind I am new to flutter so be stepwise.)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Step 1:

Open the `gradle.properties` file

[image: **Android Studio File Structure**]

Step 2:

Disable `android.enableR8=true` by adding a # in front:

`#android.enableR8=true`

Alternatively, you can swap out the R8 for D8, The build system changed to using D8 instead of R8.

`android.enableD8=true`

Comment: What is the difference between D8 and R8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549187/difference-between-d8-and-r8-android

Comment: Is this change just for Darts?!

Answer (score 0):

For me, after spending a whole day on it, I solved it by downgrading to JDK 8 and I have previously tried it with embedded JDK and JDK 16.

Comment: Downgrading something is not a valid solution