# WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

I have WARNING in run console :

```
[        ] WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
[   +2 ms] It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[   +2 ms] You will no longer be able to disable R8
```

i read another question from this problem in stackoverflow and i did the following things :

dont have android.enableR8=true in gradle.properties
added #android.enableR8=true in gradle.properties

but the problem was not resolved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [build.gradle: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558454/build-gradle-the-option-android-enabler8-is-deprecated-and-should-not-be-used)